# strlen() with logical and comparison operators not working

Tags: php, logical-operators, strlen, comparison-operators

Ok I am fairly fairly new in PHP and I am trying to make a contact form. There are some fields which I need to be of certain characters.

```
if (!empty($_POST['title'])) {
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    }
    elseif (strlen($title)>=1||strlen($title)<6)||strlen($title)>50 {
        $error .= "Length of your Subject must be more than 6 characters. <br />";
    }
else {
    $error .= "Please enter the Subject. <br />";
}
```

$error stores all the errors that came while filling the form. At the end, the form checks and if no error is found, message is successfully sent.

**What I want?**
I want to display the error stated in the elseif statement if the string length is less than 3 but greater or equal to 1. Error should also display if the length is greater than 50 characters.

If the field is empty then it should display the last error provided in else statement.

**What's happening?**
Whenever I keep the field empty it shows the first error instead of second. And if I enter say just 1 character in the field, no error is shown.

I am bagging my head, I did a lot of trial and errors but nothing seems to work.
It will be a huge help if someone can forward. This is my first project in PHP just because some of my readers want it and I have not learnt the language completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look you have jumbled the if else statements.....
try it this way ,

```
if (!empty($_POST['title'])) 
{
    $title = $_POST['title'];

    if (strlen($title)>=1 && strlen($title)<6)||strlen($title)>50)
    {
        $error .= "Length of your Subject must be more than 6 characters. <br />";
    }
}

else 
{
$error .= "Please enter the Subject. <br />";
}
```

Comment: Yup he has used else-if , but to check what data is present in $title, he must succeed in his first if statement, thats why the execution was going wrong

Comment: Yes a little change in your strlen comparisons, as Dan mentioned you must also change...

Comment: @PavanK Your code gave an unexpected BOOLEAN_OR error. So I just removed a parentheses and wallop... it worked just like I wanted :D

And those who are thinking my error message is wrong even when it is 50 characters are right. I have changed the statement so that it suits both the conditions :)

Thank you very very much for all the guys provided :)

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is `(strlen($title)>=1||strlen($title)<6)` is true all the time, because the length of the title is either >= 1 or < 6 (or both). You probably wanted to use `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: And how does a non-empty string get to that if

Comment: It is relevant for half of the problem: why is the error printed when the title is empty?

Comment: @Peter Wooster don't be fooled by the incorrect indenting, `$title` is simply undefined in that `elseif` and the condition always evaluates to `true`. The OP should use `$_POST` instead of `$title` there however to make it work at all...

Comment: I wasn't fooled by the bad formatting. As I said in my answer no non-empty value ever gets to this if.

Comment: @Peter Wooster Then I am probably confused by your use of this and that `if`. As I see it, the complete statement reads `if (!empty(...) {} elseif (true) {} else {}` so that makes this answer correct as far as I am concerned.

Comment: @jeroen I was referring to the if in the elsif that this answer discuses.  All I said was that That particular statement only gets used when the string is empty.  How you read that as my being confused by the poor formatting is very strange, the statement is true and is the basis of all the correct answers here.  It is also the case that the specific comparison in discussed in this answer needed work.  That's why I voted for Pavan K's answer.

Answer (score 0):

It only goes into the else if when the string is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Why displaying same error if the length is between 1 and 6 characters and more than 50 characters? Also your if statement is wrong at all. If it's empty you are going to `elseif` where you are using `$title` but there is not any `$title` variable defined yet.

```
if(!empty($_POST['title'])) {
    $title = $_POST['title'];

    if(strlen($title) >= 1 && strlen($title) < 6) {
        $error .= "Length of your Subject must be more than 6 characters. <br />";
    } elseif(strlen($title)>50) {
        $error .= "Length of your Subject must be no more than 50 characters. <br />";
    } else {
        // Length is between 6 and 50 characters, i.e. it is valid.
    }
} else {
    $error .= "Please enter the Subject. <br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Dan Berindei said, you use an or when you should have used an and for checking if $title wasn't empty. Actually you don't need to check that it's at least one character at all since you already verified that it's not an empty string.

Here is something a little cleaner:

```
if (!empty($_POST['title'])) {
    $title = $_POST['title'];

    if (strlen($title)<6)||strlen($title)>50) {
        $error .= "Length of your Subject must be between than 6 and 50 characters. <br />";
    }
}else {
    $error .= "Please enter the Subject. <br />";
}
```